# React app is rendering a empty screen, When it is deployed in server

Tags: reactjs, server, server-side-rendering

I am using the command 'Create-React-app' in my React based application. After developing the application and build, it is deployed in the server by using the command 'npm run build'. I observed that it is deployed in the server. But when accessing the 'URL'page in the browser, it is showing Blank info in browser. Any One can help me to solve this issue?

Note: It is working on my local system by accessing local host URL.

Index.html File

React AppYou need to enable JavaScript to run this app.!function(l){function e(e){for(var r,t,n=e[0],o=e[1],u=e[2],f=0,i=[];f

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you see any `console` errors? Are you trying server-side-rendering with pure `create-react-app`?